# I can't read data into an array

Tags: c

I'm trying to read data from a text file and copy them into an array, but my code doesn't work. This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;

    FILE *data;
    data = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    .......

    fclose(data);
}
```

and when I replace

```
data = fopen(argv[1], "r");`
```

with

```
data = fopen("(the file name)", "r");
```

it works.

this is the full code

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int i;
i=0;
FILE *data;
data = fopen(argv[1], "r");

while (!feof(data)) {
    fscanf(data, "%i", &aa[i]);
    i++;
}

fclose(data);
printf("%i\n", aa[0]);
}
```

and the text file is

```
3
2 1
2 2
2 3
```

Comment: What command line arguments are you passing when you run the program ?

Comment: Also, what is the value of ERRNO after the presumably failed call to fopen?

Comment: Should debug to see what is in argv[1] + should test if you actually have an argv[1]. Please read more doc.

Comment: What misterJ said, or if you don't want to run it in a debugger, simply printf("'%s'\n", argv[1]);

Comment: And exactly what error do you get when you run it the way that doesn't work?  compile error?  link error?  crash?  if crash, what signal?

Comment: ./ee file.txt
i get (Segmentation fault: 11) in terminal when i run

Comment: I can't see why you should get a segfault in the code you have posted.  Use either the debugger, or `printf` to find out exactly where the crash happens.  Also, if you do proper error checking (`argc > 1`, `data != NULL` etc.) these bugs become much easier to detect.

Comment: Add printf before fopen to see what file you are getting for debugging. Also I didn't see definition of aa in your code. It should be integer array big enough to store your file data.

Comment: How is `aa` declared?

Comment: Valgrind is your friend. http://valgrind.org/

Answer (score 3):

You should always write basic error checking code for anything which might reasonably fail, e.g.:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    FILE *data;

    if (argc < 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Missing arguments: %s\n", usage);
        exit(1);
    }

    data = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (data == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "fopen('%s') failed, errno = %d, argv[1], errno);
        exit(2);
    }

    .......

    fclose(data);

    return (0);
}
```

This way if `fopen` fails then (a) you won't crash and (b) you will get some useful info as to *why* the file was not opened.

Comment: If the OP is going to check for that error, he had better also check that `argc > 1`.

Comment: This is good information, but it is not an answer.  That's why I put checking the return value of fopen and errno in a comment.

Comment: @xaxxon: you may have a point, but formatted code does not work well in a comment and I felt that the OP really needed to understand the basics of error checking before proceeding any further with trying to learn C. So I guess this *is* an answer, but it's a more holistic answer to the implicit question: "what is wrong with my code ?".

Answer (score 1):

1. You might be passing the file which is not available in the current directory.
2. Give the valid file directory with file name as argument
3. check for null after 'fopen'

compile with gcc -g -Wall main.c

and use gdb debugger to identify the error

Answer (score -1):

You should pass filename while running the code.

```
./a.out file.txt.
```

If file.txt does not exist then it will throw error as segmentation fault.

Try this code, its working

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    int j = 0;
    int aa[100];    //declare an int array to store the data, as you are retrieving using %i
    i=0;
    FILE *data;
    data = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    while (!feof(data)) {
        fscanf(data, "%i", &aa[i]);
        i++;
    }
    i--;
    fclose(data);
    for(j; j < i; j++)
        printf("%i\n", aa[j]);
}
```

in file.txt give whatever data you are giving.

and while running pass **./a.out file.txt**

See to it that **file.txt is in same folder** or give whole path

Comment: OP claims that he is doing just that, which is why it is puzzling.

Comment: Does the file exist in same folder